# SOAP webservices for Android weather forecasting

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, soap-client

I created an Android application making use of web services to access the weather forecast information of any location based on the ZIP code. It connects to [WebServiceX.net](http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=68&CATID=12).  This service is limited, as it only provides information on USA forecasts.

I also tried the [Global Weather](http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=56) service hosted by WebServiceX.net as well.  The problem with this is the weather is reported at the current time only (no forecasting) and the service works with city names, it only listed a few cities in certain countries.

Is there any other international weather forecast service that is free to access with my application?

My search has only delivered results for mostly American weather services such as [National Weather Service](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/) and the ZIP code based service mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](http://forecast.io/#/f/6.9271,79.8612) after small search (but I haven't use this).
It provides "first thousand API calls every day are free".

And [this](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx) is a Free Local Weather REST API